# Allocating more than 4GB on vmware guest OS using PAE

Tags: vmware

So I'm running a 32bit ubuntu with 2GB ram.

I'm thinking of upgrading the ram to 16GB and enabling PAE to give the guest OS on vmware extra memory.

Does this mean I'll have to switch to 64bit so that the vmware can run on 64bit (and hence have extra memory), or will vmware on 32bit be able to give its guest OSes the required memory?

I mean, it seems possible to give more memory than 4GB currently, but it says that swapping may occur. The question is, would vmware running on 32bit resort to swapping when it gets beyond 4GB no matter what?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of questions on vmware on stackoverflow, and I'm trying to get XCode running with enough ram as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PAE you might be able to use 4GB or more for global system memory, but 32 bit user-mode processes will always have an upper limit of 2-4GB, even when run under 64 bit systems. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.